# If condition equal to array value

Tags: php

I have an array. Inside that array my Fruit_Name could either be Pear or Apple depending on the button i select in the previous page. Lets say i select Apple the if statement does not seem to work however it does echo. It echos`$FruitType` and it seems to get Apple which should fire up my if statement and show me "You did it!", but my if condition doesn't. What am i doing wrong?

**Array**

Fruit_Name=Apple

**My Function**

```
    function GetField($arr, $field)
    {
        $result = '       ';
        foreach($arr as $line)
        {
            if (explode('=', $line) [0] == $field)
            {
                $result = explode('=', $line) [1];
            }

        }

        return $result;
    }

    $FruitType= GetField($array, 'Fruit_Name');

    echo $FruitType;

    if ($FruitType == "Apple")
    {
        echo "You did it!";
    }
    else if ($FruitType == "Pear")
    {
        echo "Its not Pear!";
    }
```

Comment: `if (explode('=', $line) [0] == $field)` thats not going to work the way you seem to think it will

Comment: Ill look into that. Thanks.

Comment: what you call an array is just a string, so the foreach wont work either

Comment: @Dagon how should the explode statement be written?

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings (and really, you should do this with any data type) in php, you must use the === notation. The == is only used for numbers, and when used on strings leads to problems like the one you're facing.

So your code should be

`If ( $FruitType === "Apple" )`

And the Getfield function is incorrect, as mentioned and explained by Dagon.